# isinstance operator returning false on inheritance

Tags: python

I have created 2 classes A & B, B inherits A. I'm using the isinstance to check if b is of type a and it returns false. Shouldn't be true?

```
class a():pass

class b(a):pass

print isinstance(b,a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

No. `b` is an instance of either `type` or `classobj`, *not* of `a`. You may want [the `issubclass` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass) instead.

```
>>> issubclass(b, a)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

b is class, not object, so it is not instance of any class. To get True, call isinstance(b(),a)

Comment: It is actually an instance of one of two classes. But it is not an instance of `a`.